# How to mute a looped background video

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, playback, mute

I am using the [Wallpaper plugin](http://formstone.it/components/Wallpaper/demo/index.html) to loop a video in the background of a div. The idea is to have a video loop in a background of a div on mute. On hover, the video will have sound.

I couldn't find documentation or ways to mute. Any thoughts? I have tried to mute by adding the lines after the plugin is initialized --

```
$("video").prop('muted', true);
$("video").attr('muted', 'muted');
```

Comment: have you tried $("video").prop('muted', 'muted');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen a reference to the volume of the video in the documentation of the plugin.
However, in an html compliant browser, it can be easily muted by

1. Asserting the `muted` property
2. Setting the `volume` property to 0

You can do it on the `video` elements or on the jQuery wrapper.

```
$('video').prop('volume', 0)
$('video').prop('muted', true)
```

Since the video elements in your document are created by the wallpaper plugin, you should set the `volume` or `muted` property after these have been appended to the DOM. It should not be necessary, but  in case of problems you could try setting an event handler for the `wallpaper.loaded` event.

```
$('your selector').wallpaper({
   //... initialization parameters
}).on('wallpaper.loaded', function(){
  $('video', this).prop('muted', true);
});
```

Comment: excellent! doing the on event handle with wallpaper loaded did the trick. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the property muted="muted" to get the desired result, so long as there's only one video element on the page that will work just fine.

```
$("video").prop('muted', 'muted');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pz5x4/1/)**

**Edit**

FYI I checked out the wallpaper plugin and saw that it did indeed do what I suspected which is create a video object. If you really wanted to get specific on what video does what you can use the element that wraps the video then the child video element such as:

```
$("#pluginElem > video").prop('muted', 'muted');
```